# wxWidgets - wxGrid - reading/writing non string cell values

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxGrid to edit an array of numerical data.

I was wondering what's the best way to get non-string data in and out of the cells without going through the string to numeric conversion all the time.
I've used SetCellEditor() to control the data entry.

currently I use this:

```
// numeric value into cell
str.clear();
str << val1;
m_grid4->SetCellValue(row, col, str);
..
// read value from back into variable
val = atoi(m_grid4->GetCellValue(row, col));
```

Apart from the fact that atoi() is a bit ugly and a template function with a stringstream would be better, is there a way do get non-string values a bit better in and out of cells?

I was looking at the editors and renderers but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worry about efficiency, you almost certainly should use a custom table class deriving from `wxGridTableBase` instead of using the default trivial `wxGridStringTable` implementation which stores everything as strings. Then, and much less importantly, if it makes sense in your case, you can use `wxGridCellNumberRenderer` which will call your table `GetValueAsLong()` method instead of `GetValue()` (which returns a string).

Both of those are demonstrated in [wxGrid sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/grid/griddemo.cpp), notably look at `BugsGridTable` there.

Good luck!

Comment: I had already compiled and played with that wxGrid sample but didn't see what I was looking for. I'll have a closer look at    wxGridTableBase

Comment: Looks like I got lots to learn here. My grid is just a plain wxGrid. No explicit table type defined. I created it with `wxFormBuilder` which does only this one kind of grid. So I think I'll have to create it by code instead and use the `wxGridTableBase`

Comment: @ahagele, you don't need to recreate you grid. Just create a custom table derived from the wxGridTableBase and assign it to the grid. It will still be wxGrid, but it will be using you own table implementation.